# Jhipster generator doesn't generate filter panel in UI

Tags: filter, jhipster

I am using jhipster to generate CRUD for my web application.
by configuring jdl generator I expect to see search panel in UI for each entity. But it just generates EntityQueryService classes in backend,it works fine 
and it is reachable in swagger-ui in the API docs page
Is there any UI library thing to help me pass parameters as expected format or any predicate filter panel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I addded manual search panel as below :

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="field_billOrgType">organization</label>
                <select id="field_billOrgType" ng-model="vm.searchModel.billOrgType">
                    <option ng-repeat="x in vm.Utilities" value="{{x.key}}">{{x.name}} - {{x.key}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My controller:

```
( function () {
    'use strict';
     angular
         .module('ebppApp')
         .factory('TmpBill', TmpBill);
 TmpBill.$inject = ['$resource'];
 function TmpBill($resource) {
     var resourceUrl = 'api/tmp-bills/:id';

     return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
         'search': {
             method: 'GET'
             , isArray: true
             , url: 'api/tmp-bills?:billOrgType',
             params: {
                 billOrgType: '@billOrgType'
             }
             }
         }
     });
 } })();

     function search() {

         TmpBill.search({

             billOrgType: vm.searchModel.billOrgType ? "billOrgType.equals=" + vm.searchModel.billOrgType : ''
             page: vm.page - 1,
             size: vm.itemsPerPage,
             sort: sort()
         }, onSuccess, onError);
         function sort() {
             var result = [vm.predicate + ',' + (vm.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
             if (vm.predicate !== 'id') {
                 result.push('id');
             }
             return result;
         }

         function onSuccess(data, headers) {
             vm.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
             vm.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
             vm.queryCount = vm.totalItems;
             vm.tmpBills = data;
             // vm.page = pagingParams.page;
         }

         function onError(error) {
             AlertService.error(error.data.message);
         }
     }
```